# Validating forms with Regular Expressions (Javascript Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input form which needs to be validated in real time (.Keyup and .Load)

It should allow all A-z characters (Upper & lower) and the symbols "'", "-" and " " (apostrophe, dash and whitespace).

At the moment this is what I have: ([A-Za-z]-\s\')*
and I'm using it like this:

```
var regex = /([A-Za-z]\-\s\')*/;
if (string == "") {
  turn textbox border grey (default)
} else if (!regex.test(string)) {
  turn textbox border red
} else {
  turn textbox border green
}
```

All it does it change the the textbox green every time (Unless it's blank - it goes grey). 
What's the correct expression/technique and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it that does not work? What are you expecting to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: I've already answered these questions.
What doesn't work: The regular expression test.
What am I expecting: Read the code. If it meets the regex conditions then it should turn the input field you are typing into green. else it should turn red. It is grey when blank.
What's happening: It turns green no matter what you type in.

Comment: So, if the key is a character they just released, `          ` or `---------` or `''''''''''''''''` are valid input? Can't you narrow that down to edge conditions of some type of actual final validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like the following:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z\-\s']*$/;
```

The `^` and `$` are beginning and end of string anchors, respectively.  Without these the match could start or end anywhere in the string.  Since `*` means "repeat the previous element zero or more times" you will match every string no matter the contents because the regex can successfully match zero characters.

The other issue with your current regex is that `[A-Za-z]\-\s\'` will try to match a letter, a dash, a single whitespace character, and an apostrophe in order (4 characters total).  To match any one of those options you need to put them all inside of the character class (square brackets), or use alternation with the pipe character (`|`) which would look like `([A-Za-z]|-|\s|')`.  Alternation is more general but character classes are the preferred method for something like this.

Regarding the escaping, apostrophe has no special meaning in regular expressions so it does not need to be escaped.  A dash only needs to be escaped if it is inside of a character class (if it isn't escaped it is interpreted as part of a range).

Comment: I was just about to post that. Haha you beat me to it! +1

Comment: does the apostrophe not require a backslash before it?

Comment: @Pete Edited my answer with some more info about the escaping, no need for the backslash before the apostrophe (although the regex should work the same way if you include it).

Comment: Couldn't you replace `A-Za-z` with `\w` and just add `i` as a flag? If you are wanting to shorten it. haha :p

Comment: @Pete Why? It's not a special regex character.

Comment: @ShawnGrav `\w` will also match underscores and digits, but you could use `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]` with the `i` flag.

Comment: @ShawnGrav `\w` is not equivalent to `[A-Za-z]`. `\w` will also match numbers and _.

Comment: @F.J Riiight, I apologize for my foolishness :p

Comment: This is a perfect answer :) Thank you! I'll accept it as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @Pete it would, as stated by F.J and plax. I was incorrect and it would also match against underscores and digits, and yes the i flag means the regex would be case insensitive

Comment: Might be a bit a bit late on this one. but is there a way to make it so they can only put one "-" or "'" or "\s" at a time?

Comment: @Pete Might be better as a new question, but you should be able to add something like `(?!.*([\-'\s]).*\1)` to the beginning of the regex to enforce that restriction.